# what can i do to put files from local machine to my remote machine in local network?

Tags: ftp

I have been installed `vsftpd` to exchange files from one computer to another one and vice versa. When I've connected to my remote machine using `ftp -A -a 192.168.0.32` - I've got the following output:

```
Connected to 192.168.0.32.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.5)
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

Then, when I try to put file from my local computer to my remote machine using `put 10.mp4` - I get the following:

```
local: 10.mp4 remote: 10.mp4
200 EPRT command successful. Consider using EPSV.
553 Could not create file.
```

I get error `553 Could not create file.`
Please tell me - what can I do to resolve this problem?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your `ftp` client doesn't have write access to the target directory. A `cd /tmp` before your `put` will help. You'll have to `mv` the files from the remote system's `/tmp` later.

Comment: @waltinator, I get `550 Failed to change directory` error. Possibly this info will useful - I have marked as a home directory for ftp the whole `sda3` partition using command `sudo usermod -d /media/reiji/1F3B910146CE45A7 ftp`. Filesystem of this partition is NTFS if it's matter.

Comment: @Also, I tried to know from which user I try to execute any command in `ftp>`. I've been executed `!whoami`, but have been received as output `reiji`.

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman Why FTP? Why not sftp/scp?

Comment: @vidarlo, I'm newbie and it seems simplest for me, more complicated things are hard for me at this moment. Are SFTP & SCP more simple in use?

Comment: Yes. No configuration needed, just install `openssh-server` and enable it. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openssh In addition FTP is a 40 year old protocol that is fundamentally broken in many aspects, such as lack of encryption and use of extra ports.

Comment: @vidarlo, Thanks! I will try to use it.